# Unable to install Rhipe package for R version 3.0.2 in ubuntu-12.04

Tags: r

I have ubuntu 12.04 OS with R 3.0.2 version. My problem is I am getting message like "Rhipe packages is not available for R version 3.0.2".

Please let me know in case you have a workaround or any solution for installing Rhipe in R 3.0.2 (for Ubuntu).

Regards,

Comment: Please **edit your original question** and indicate how you are trying to install this package. There are several ways to install a R package. Are you installing from inside R or are you using a PPA and installing using the Ubuntu Software Center, or the `apt-get` command?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the _exact_ command you used to try and install the package.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the package is not available from CRan apparently. However, a quick search gives the Rhipe [home page](http://www.datadr.org/install.html) that has the very clear instructions reproduced bellow:

1. Install Hadoop

   > Prior to doing anything else, it is critical to ensure that the cluster on which RHIPE will be installed has a working Hadoop cluster. RHIPE works with Apache Hadoop 1.0.x (0.20.x)
   >
   > The following are useful references on installing Apache Hadoop on a [single](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) and [multi-node](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/#conf-site-xml-all-machines) cluster. Alternatively, one might wish to have a more streamlined install, which can be accomplished with the [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/) distribution's installation manager.
   >
   > It is good to ensure the Hadoop works prior to installing RHIPE. A simple test is to run an example job and see if it completes without errors. To run a minimal example, run the following from the hadoop directory (assuming hadoop version 1.0.3).

   ```
   hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.3.jar pi 10 100
   ```
2. R must be installed as a shared library, I will not include the details since you presumably already have it installed. See the Rhipe link above for more info.
3. Install protocol buffers

   ```
   wget http://protobuf.googlecode.com/files/protobuf-2.4.1.tar.gz
   tar -xzf protobuf-2.4.1.tar.gz
   cd protobuf-2.4.1
   ./configure # --prefix=...
   make
   make install
   ```
4. Set up environment variables

   > PKG_CONFIG_PATH: make sure this contains a path to where the protobuf*.pc files are located.
   >
   > LD_LIBRARY_PATH: points to the path where R.so and Rhipe.so are located (typically something like **PREFIX**/lib64/R/lib).
   >
   > HADOOP: points to the Hadoop installation directory. It is expected that $HADOOP/bin contains the Hadoop shell executable hadoop.
5. Install Rhipe

   ```
   wget http://ml.stat.purdue.edu/rhipebin/Rhipe_0.73.1.tar.gz
   R CMD INSTALL Rhipe_0.73.1.tar.gz
   ```

Comment: In my experience I had to start R with admin rights to install things from within R. That is, you may have to use `sudo R CMD INSTALL Rhipe_0.73.1.tar.gz`, and enter your password when prompted.

Comment: @user68186 not necessarily, R can install into your $HOME also: `* installing to library ‘/home/terdon/.Rlibs’`.

Comment: Thanks. My R skills are a bit rusty. I did want the R packages to be available to other users, and sudo was the way to go.